# Which documents should I read to understand how to use a c compiler in VS code?

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code

When I try to run "hello-world.c", it asks me to choose a launch configuration from the list:  Chrome, Edge, Go, Node.js. Under what conditions is a launch configuration required and under what conditions is it optional?

It seems VS code did not understand that I was trying to compile a C program. I say that because it offered me Go and Node.js but not C or C++.

Perhaps I need to try each of the several dozen extensions that were suggested when I chose "More."

Here is the c code

```
include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("hello world")
}
```

Comment: You don't need any extension. You do need to run `gcc` on the command line, in some terminal emulator (probably as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). You should read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: Have you checked the VS Code docs for C/C++ and gcc? For [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux), [Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), and [WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl). (The tutorials show g++, but the flow for C and gcc is mostly the same.)